# Notification Center - Obervers not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, nsnotificationcenter

I'm developing an app which has to communicate with an external accessory. The app has several requests to send to the external accessory.

My problem:

I'm using observers in different places (classes), I'm adding the following observers in `viewDidLoad`:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
selector:@selector(observer1:)
    name:EADSessionDataReceivedNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
selector:@selector(observer2:)
    name:EADSessionDataReceivedNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
selector:@selector(observer3:)
    name:EADSessionDataReceivedNotification object:nil];
```

The 1st Observer works very well, but I'm getting problems with the other two. They don't respond until the first one has been used. Do I need to add something else?

The flow is as follows:

1. Send a request to ext-acc and fire a flag to know which observer will take the returned data
2. ext-acc responds with data
3. The receiver method pushes a notification into notification center.
4. The observer with the flag in 1 will take the data (at this point do I need to remove the notification since no one else will need it?).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you register 3 observers for the same notification then all three will be called (sequentially) for each event.

Comment: Sorry, it seems like the observers are not catching the notification but observer1 at the beginning

Comment: I don't know if do I need to move the "addobserver" to viewWillAppear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks you have a misunderstanding regarding how `NSNotificationCenter` works. You are registering your object (`self`) to observe the notification `EADSessionDataReceivedNotification` three times, each with it's own selector (`observer1`, `observer2`, `observer3`).

So, what is happening is correct for your code as written. When `EADSessionDataReceivedNotification` is posted, `NSNotificationCenter` sends the specified selector to each observer. There is no conditional logic or way to cancel a notification.

Given your description, it sounds like you should only be observing the notification once and checking your flag to determine how to process. Something like:

```
// observe notificaton
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(dataReceived:) object:nil];

// notification handler
- (void)dataReceived:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if (someCondition) {
        [self handleDataCondition1];
    }
    else if (aSecondCondition) {
        [self handleDataCondition2];
    }
    else if (aThirdCondition) {
        [self handleDataCondition3];
    }
    else {
        // ????
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so another question is, do I need to do something like "remove" the notification after enter into the observer? or it is handled automatically by the app?

Comment: You must call removeObserver in dealloc since you are adding the observer in viewDidLoad. If you moved the add observer code to one of the viewXAppear methods, then you should unsubscribe in one of the viewXDisappear methods.